# Replace Cobertura with JaCoCo in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, code-coverage, jacoco

Currently i am running an angular 8 application. By default angular is using Cobertura to generate the coverage report. Is it possible to replace this Cobertura with Jacoco? If yes then how? I searched a lot but didn't find any suitable answer for that. Most of the examples are for JAVA so just curious to know whether is it possible for JAVASCRIPT or not. Here is the test config form angular.json file.

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "codeCoverage": true,
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "scripts": [],
        "styles": [
          "src/assets/scss/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
        ],
        "assets": ["src/assets", "src/manifest.json"]
      }
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you really use Cobertura, because both Cobertura (https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/) and JaCoCo (https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco) are for languages that run on Java Virtual Machine such as Java, not for JavaScript.

In any case, the answer on your question: no, you can not use JaCoCo for JavaScript.

Comment: For coverage i am using karma and karma supports cobertura. https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter

Comment: @SRana Karma ( https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html ) is a test runner, https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter is a reporter for Instanbul tool ( https://istanbul.js.org/ ) and this reporter able to produce **Cobertura format**, but it does not use Cobertura tool ( https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/ ) In any case, the answer on your question: no, you can not use JaCoCo tool ( https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco ) for JavaScript.

Comment: No, BUT you CAN get a Jacoco compatible report file.